# Textarea and Textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

We are able to provide a connection to a textbox using ADO.net to the database...but if we are willing to specify a particular region for our text then we are unable to use textarea in this case as far as sql connection through sql server is concerned.We are bound to use multiline textbox for this situation.Why textarea doesn't support connectin with the database?
Can anybody help me out???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a multi-line textbox on your asp.net form and view the form in a browser. Right click on your form in the browser and select "View Source" (or your favorite browser's equivalent).  Examine the source to find your multi-tline textbox, and you'll discover that it already is a textarea.

Furthermore, as far as your browser is concerned there is no such thing as a textbox.  It's really just an `<input >` element who `type` attribute is set to "text".